# Line increment in gnuplot

Tags: sed, gnuplot

I have large files (~5 Gbs) whit constant increment on x-axis, let's say each *dt*.

I would like to know if I could set the `every` command of Gnuplot as logarithmic increment not linear.

`plot "fileA.txt" u 1:2 every dt #linear increment of dt`

This is because, if x-axis is in log-scale, then I want to have more points for low values of x in (10^-4,10^-2) but also not an oversampling in (10^4,10^2) range. Somehow a differential increment.

Does I have to use external programs like `sed` to re-write my file first?

A test plot is included as well as the data. [image: Plot] In blue the full data, in red the ones with the `every` command. As you can see one loose the information for short x also oversample the plot for large x. [the data file](http://www.filedropper.com/fort)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could plot smoothed data with points:

```
set key left
set logscale x
set yrange [3.9:4.8]

set samples 30

set terminal png
set output "log.png"
plot "fort.11" title "raw" with points lc 3 pointtype 5 pointsize 2,\
     "" title "smooth" smooth csplines with points lc 1 pointtype 5 pointsize 1
```

- `set samples 30` tells gnuplot to use 30 points equidistant in x
- `smooth csplines` interpolates the datapoints
- `with points` plots with points instead of lines, which would be the default

Note that this does not plot the original data, and that `smooth csplines` introduces new points if the original        datapoints are too far apart. This might or might not be what you want.

[image: compare original and smoothed data]